# Is there a limit to number of hats earned on a single day?

Tags: discussion

As part of the christmas bash we see hats being handed out. My question Is there a limit to the number of hats you earn in a day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, no limits on the number of hats you can earn per day! However, there's a finite number of hats total, and the event runs until 4 January. How you use that information is up to you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to say, in all forms of unoffical, say no.